# iOS Calendar View in Objective-C for iOS 9+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I'm looking for a mature, well maintained Objective-C Calendar View for iOS compatible with iOS 9+ which can be implemented in my application. I want to achieve something similar to the attached design.

Many of the calendars I have looked at are either written in Swift or not maintained.

[Example of what I want the Calendar View to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8lxB.png)

As you can see in the example i need the following features available in the library

- Ability to add a superscript in a calendar cell
- Ability to add a custom icons in a calendar cell
- Ability to highlight today's date
- Ability to have a background on the calendar

I have tried FSCalendar but it appears it doesn't meet all of those requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar). With some customization you should be able to achieve that result. I used it in [this app](https://github.com/FancyPixel/gulps) to provide a calendar fairly similar to yours (each day shows progress with an accessory view).

Comment: Thank you, this looks to be exactly what we need, I've looked at this before but was a little cautious as it hasn't been updated in 3 months and from your example project I can see it meets the requirements for our implementation.